# counter_cache doesn't works

Tags: caching, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

If I execute in rails console (dev or in unit test ENV) :

```
u = User.first
puts u.topics_number # 0
Topic.create!(user: u)
puts u.topics_number # 0
puts u.reload
puts u.topics_number # 1
```

where topics_number is counter_cache in Topic class like :

```
belongs_to :user, counter_cache: :topics_number
```

topics_number is in table users.

**How can I do to force update without reload?**

I have a process to do in `after_create` and I have to get the good value of this cache_counter !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not update `u.topics_number` without a reload. It's the way how ActiveRecord works in Rails. You take something at a specific time and create a Ruby object out of that. Anything which happens after that moment in the database is not getting automagically recognised by the Ruby object. You have to `.reload`!

What you can do is the following:

```
puts User.first.topics_number # 0
Topic.create!(user: User.first)
puts User.first.topics_number # 1
```

Instead of the `first` method you could use `where(id: u.id).first`.

Comment: Rails can be update counter when created and pass the object, because it can detect cache _counter for this relation. but ok, I reload...